# Not able to generate Partner.jar

Tags: wsdl, salesforce

I want to integrate java with salesforce for that I'm trying to generate partner.jar, I'm following this link

[Introduction to the Force.com Web Services Connector](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Introduction_to_the_Force.com_Web_Services_Connector)

I'm using Partner WSDL API. I'm stuck with generating Partner.jar file,

need some help here ..!!

I'm using command **my command is **java -classpath J:\Practice\force-wsc-36.1.1.jar com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc J:\Practice\Partner.wsdl .\Partner.jar**
now the exception is

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/stringtemplate/v4
/STGroupDir

        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.stringtemplate.v4.STGroupDir
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to generate partner.jar using WSDL file and you are using "force-wsc-36.1.1.jar" (File as Web Service Connector).

As of WSC-36 connector required an additional framework to generate "partner.jar" call "StringTemplate engine framework".

Download latest "StringTemplate binary" jar file using below link: [String Template jar file](http://www.stringtemplate.org/download.html)

Put that String template jar, wsc jar and WSDL files in one location.

1. Open CMD
2. Go to the directory where you put your all files.
3. Fire below command to generate a partner.jar file.

   **java -classpath force-wsc-36.1.1.jar;ST-4.0.8.jar com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc partner.wsdl partner.jar**

   *Syntax*: **Java -classpath [WSC jar file];[String template jar file] com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc [Partner.wsdl file] [Ouput file name with .jar extation]**

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a folder named `wsdl` in your `C:\` drive and copy following jars in to it:
   **[force-wsc-54.0.0.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/force/api/force-wsc/54.0.0/force-wsc-54.0.0.jar) [ST-4.3.1.jar](https://github.com/antlr/website-st4/raw/gh-pages/download/ST-4.3.1.jar) [rhino-1.7.14.jar](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino/releases) [antlr-4.0-complete.jar](https://www.antlr.org/download/index.html)**
2. Open **cmd** and run:

```
java -classpath C:\wsdl\force-wsc-54.0.0.jar;C:\wsdl\ST-4.3.1.jar;C:\wsdl\rhino-1.7.14.jar;C:\wsdl\antlr-4.0-complete.jar com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc partner.wsdl.xml C:\wsdl\sf-partner.jar
```

Note: `C:\wsdl\sf-partner.jar` is a generated `.jar` stub file